# Change the variable value in an other plugin function with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I try to change a class, which is stored in a variable without making any changes in the plugin file. I'm not sure how to target the variable inside the function.

This is the function: `function learndash_mark_complete( $post, $atts = array() ) {` Inside this function, there is a variable called `$button_class`.

```
if ( isset( $atts['button']['class'] ) ) {
    $button_class = ' class="learndash_mark_complete_button ' . esc_attr( $atts['button']['class'] ) . '" ';
} else {
    $button_class = ' class="learndash_mark_complete_button" ';
}
```

Is there a simple way to change the code to..

```
if ( isset( $atts['button']['class'] ) ) {
    $button_class = ' class="myclass' . esc_attr( $atts['button']['class'] ) . '" ';
} else {
    $button_class = ' class="myclass" ';
}
```

without change the plugin file. Maybe to create a function in functions.php or in a seperate (new) plugin?

I saw articles on the internet about `add_filter`, but I'm not sure how to target the part I need without wipe the whole function.

I know I could change the class with jQuery or something, and maybe it should be a lot easier, but I like to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

If plugin does not provide filter hook to change the class name then you can not you filter value.

But, if you are writing your own plugin then you can use this type of logic to change the value without touching original source.

This code should be in the plugin file,

```
$arrayToFilter = array(
    'class_name' => 'learndash_mark_complete_button',
    'key1' => 'value1', // So on
 );
$value = apply_filters( 'change_class', $arrayToFilter ); 
if ( isset( $atts['button']['class'] ) ) {
    $button_class = ' class="'.$value['class_name'].'' . esc_attr( $atts['button']['class'] ) . '" ';
} else {
    $button_class = ' class="'.$value['class_name'].'" ';
}
```

And add this filter into theme functions.php file to modify change_class hook's value

```
function example_callback($args) {
    // Here you can get $arrayToFilter as $args 
    $args['class_name'] = 'myclass';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'change_class', 'example_callback',10 , 1 ); // Where $priority is 10, $accepted_args is 1.
```

I hope you got basic idea of add_filter().